# Cancel all sagas in Redux-saga

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm using React Native and I need to cancel and recreate all sagas on hot reload. I know about `cancel(tasks)` but the problem is that I have no reference to tasks after hot reload (if I assign them to a variable they get `undefined`) but some sagas still "hold on" to the previous app state for some reason and I need to cancel them all without having a reference to them.

How can I cancel all sagas, without having a reference to them explicitly, e.g. something like `sagaMiddleware.cancelAll()` (this method doesn't exist I made it up for example)?

Comment: Maybe this github issue can help you with that [How to cancel "all"](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/988)

Comment: @Luka this is exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid as it takes an argument of the tasks, which is the root of my problem in the first place.